# Navigation bar disappears and background color does not change

Tags: ios, swift

This is very irritating.

In my AppDelegate, I set the navigation bar color like this and it works fine:

```
nav.navigationBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1176, green: 0.251, blue: 0.4863, alpha: 1) /* #1e407c - B = 48%  */
```

This line does not work anywhere else.  I have another navigation controller and I want to set its bar color to the same color.

I tried putting this in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, and where I instantiate a new navigation controller.

I also tried setting the tint color.

**Edit**: It works when I set the barTintColor.

Comment: 1) Have you solved your question in your edit? 2) Your question title seems to not match the actual question.

Comment: Not really.  Why doesn't the above code work?  I think it may be an Xcode bug, so I'm going to restart it, and if it works, I will take my question down

Comment: setting the barTintColor is how you set the background color. Does that work for you?

Comment: No, .backgroundColor

Comment: navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green try using this if it works